# Get annotations from ObjectPropertyAssertion OWLAPI

Tags: java, owl, owl-api

I'm using the OWL API for OWL 2.0 and there is one thing I can't seem to figure out. I have an OWL/XML file and I would like to retrieve the annotations for my object property assertions. Here are snippets from my OWL/XML and Java code:

OWL:

```xml
<ObjectPropertyAssertion>
  <Annotation>
    <AnnotationProperty abbreviatedIRI="rdfs:comment"/>
    <Literal datatypeIRI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Bob likes sushi</Literal>
  </Annotation>
  <ObjectProperty IRI="#Likes"/>
  <NamedIndividual IRI="#UserBob"/>
  <NamedIndividual IRI="#FoodSushi"/>
</ObjectPropertyAssertion>
```

Java:

```
OWLIndividual bob = manager.getOWLDataFactory().getOWLNamedIndividual(IRI.create(base + "#UserBob"));
OWLObjectProperty likes = manager.getOWLDataFactory().getOWLObjectProperty(IRI.create(base + "#Likes"));
OWLIndividual sushi = factory.getOWLNamedIndividual(IRI.create(base + "#FoodSushi"));

OWLObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom ax =  factory.getOWLObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom(likes, bob, sushi);

  for(OWLAnnotation a: ax.getAnnotations()){
    System.out.println(a.getValue());
  }
```

Problem is, nothing gets returned even though the OWL states there is one `rdfs:comment`. It has been troublesome to find any documentations on how to retrieve this information. Adding axioms with comments or whatever is not an issue.

Comment: Does other code within the `if(ax.isAnnotated()) { … }` block get executed?  That is, is `as.isAnnotated()` returning true?  As it stands, the issue could lie with it returning false, or with `ax.getAnnotations()` returning an empty iterable.  It will help to determine which is happening.

Comment: The `ax.isAnnotated()` does return false and the `Set<OWLAnnotations>` is empty. I have removed the if-statement to avoid confusion. Thanks.

Comment: If you're using `factory.getOWLObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom(…)`, are you creating a new axiom, as opposed to retrieving one from the ontology?  What happens if you use [`OWLOntology#getObjectPropertyAssertionAxioms`](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLOntology.html#getObjectPropertyAssertionAxioms(org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLIndividual)) to find the axiom that you're looking for, and check whether that one `isAnnotated`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to retrieve the annotations you need to walk over the axioms of interest. Using the `getSomething()` adds things to the ontology, as noted in the comments, it is not possible to retrieve your axiom this way. Here is the code adapted from the [OWL-API guide](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/owled2011_tutorial.pdf):

```
//Get rdfs:comment
final OWLAnnotationProperty comment = factory.getRDFSComment();

//Create a walker
OWLOntologyWalker walker = 
                        new OWLOntologyWalker(Collections.singleton(ontology));

//Define what's going to visited
OWLOntologyWalkerVisitor<Object> visitor = 
                                new OWLOntologyWalkerVisitor<Object>(walker) {

  //In your case you visit the annotations made with rdfs:comment
  //over the object properties assertions
  @Override
  public Object visit(OWLObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom axiom) {
    //Print them
    System.out.println(axiom.getAnnotations(comment));
    return null;
  }
};

//Walks over the structure - triggers the walk
walker.walkStructure(visitor);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very helpful. Just to clarify for others, override the `visit(OWLObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom ax)` to retrieve annotations from assertion axioms.

Comment: Hi again, but in this case, how can you get annotations of a specific object property assertion (in this case, it is Likes)? As far as I understand, the walker only gets annotations of all object property assertions in the ontology.